# Parsing XML file with duplicate tags

Tags: xml, bash, perl, xml-parsing, gpx

I currently use an XML parser to extract the name of a route from a GPX (XML) file.

Each GPX files contains a single "name" tag which is what I've been extracting.

Here's the script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

gpxpath=/mnt/gpxfiles; export gpxpath

for file in $gpxpath/*
do

filename=`ls $file`; export filenanme
gpxname=`$scripts/xmlparse.pl "$file"`

echo $filename "    "$gpxname >> gpxparse.tmp

done

sort -k 2,2 gpxparse.tmp > gpxparse.out

cat gpxparse.out
```

And here's xmlparse.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'name' => sub { print $_ ->text }
    }
    )->parse( <> );
```

Here's an example GPX file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="creator" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>     
        <referrer>Referrer</referrer>
        <time>2019-06-17T06:02:23.000Z</time>
    </metadata>
    <trk>
        <name>Another GPX file</name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lon="-1.91990" lat="53.00131">
                <ele>112.1</ele>
                <time>2019-06-17T06:02:23.000Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lon="-1.91966" lat="53.00126">
                <ele>113.6</ele>
                <time>2019-06-17T06:02:25.000Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lon="-1.91962" lat="53.00125">
                <ele>114.1</ele>
                <time>2019-06-17T06:02:25.000Z</time>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lon="-1.91945" lat="53.00120">
                <ele>115.5</ele>
                <time>2019-06-17T06:02:26.000Z</time>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

I can successfully extract the name of the route using the scripts above However, I'd additionally like to extract the first co-ordinate pair in each file.

Atrack can defined by a "trk" element and within a track can be multiple segments or "trkseg".  Finally, within a trkseg are multiple "trkpt" (track points).

A track point usually consists of a latitdue and longitude co-ordinate pair along with elevation and timestamp information.

I'm only looking to extract the first lat and lon within the first trkpt of the GPX file.  Ideally, once the script has found the first co-ordinate pair it should exit and move onto the next file.

I've tried crafting an additional perl script

I've added an additional perl parse script using XML::Twig but it seems to stumble when there are multiple elements with duplicate names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) to extract the "name" value and the lat and lon of the first trkpt:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:name'          -o , \
                  -v '//_:trkpt[1]/@lat' -o , \
                  -v '//_:trkpt[1]/@lon' -n \
                  file.xml
```

```
Another GPX file,53.00131,-1.91990
```

In the shell script, you can parse this output with:

```sh
IFS=, read -r gpxname lat long < <( xmlstarlet ... )
```

Comment: No, that's a bash [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution). It would be somewhat equivalent to `read ... <<< "$(xmlstarlet ...)"` but it behaves like a redirection from a file.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've used this method to crunch through 3.5 million GPX files and it's picked up on quite a few invalid files that I otherwise wouldn't have known about - again, great solution thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Since you were originally going for a Perl solution,

```sh
perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $ARGV[0] );
   my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
   $xpc->registerNs( gpx => "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" );
   CORE::say
      join ",",
         $xpc->findnodes(q{/gpx:gpx/gpx:trk/gpx:name}, $doc),
         $xpc->findnodes(q{/gpx:gpx/gpx:trk/gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt[1]/@lat}, $doc),
         $xpc->findnodes(q{/gpx:gpx/gpx:trk/gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt[1]/@long}, $doc);
' "$file"
```

(I used XML::LibXML instead of XML::Twig because I'm more familiar with that.)

Unlike the solution in the earlier answer,

- This solution doesn't make fragile assumptions about what the default namespace might be.
- This solution doesn't make fragile assumptions about where `name` elements might or might not appear.

Comment: Thanks for this but I can't seem to get this solution to execute against a test XML file.  `
XPath error : Invalid expression
/gpx:gpx/gpx:trk/gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt[1]/
                                         ^ at -e line 5.
`   The namespace is likely to change so I'd probably consider using like "gpx version" rather than a topografix stamped ns

Comment: I originally had single quotes around the XPath. I forgot to escape the `@` when I switched to double quotes. Fixed

Comment: Re "*The namespace is likely to change*", That's not true. The namespace defines the format. The namespace CANNOT change. Ever. A different XML format will have a different namespace, but then the queries will be different to because it's a different XML format. (The *prefixes* can change all the time, though. Note that the choice of `gpx` for the XPath is completely arbitrary. I could just as easily have used `foo`.)

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy for [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s input.xml -e 'join((//name,//trkpt[1]/@*),",")'
Another GPX file,-1.91990,53.00131
```

> *Ideally, once the script has found the first co-ordinate pair it should exit and move onto the next file.*

`xidel`, together with the integrated [EXPath File Module](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#modulefile), can do this very efficiently:

```
xidel -se 'file:list("/mnt/gpxfiles")'   # lists all files in '/mnt/gpxfiles' (and subdirs!)
xidel -se 'file:list("/mnt/gpxfiles",false(),"*.xml")'   # lists all xml-files in '/mnt/gpxfiles'

xidel -se '
  for $x in file:list("/mnt/gpxfiles") return
  doc("/mnt/gpxfiles/"||$x)/join((//name,//trkpt[1]/@*),",")
'   # iterate over and parse all xml-files in '/mnt/gpxfiles' AND extract the info you need.
```

Comment: Thanks, I've not come across xidel before but the entire process will actually be parsing co-ordinate pairs to a reverse geocoding api to return the geographical location - returned from the API as json array - currently using jq but I'll play with xidel and see what it can do :)

Comment: @Huskie69 `xidel` is a bit like `curl`, `jq` and `xmlstarlet`/`xmllint` all wrapped in one, so there's a good chance `xidel` can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I see some more elegant methods in other answers, but I'd probably use a brute force method:

```
grep name {file} | head -1
grep "trkpt lon" {file} | head -1
```

and then use perl or sed to edit the result to the parts wanted.